# Shared Element Transition from nested RecyclerView to fragment: fade works, move doesnt

Tags: shared-element-transition, nestedrecyclerview

Shared Element Transaction have a set of provided transistion types, slide_top, slide_bottom, fade, move etc in android.R.transition.

My app : API 21 :: Single activity

Fragment1 :
Nested Recyclerview: A vertical recycler view, where each element is a horizontal recycler view. Each element in the latter is an image view fetched with Picasso.

Fragment 2: 
Detail view with larger sized image.

I went through various posts like [this one](https://medium.com/@DeepakDroid/share-element-transition-between-recycler-view-and-fragment-8ce5084fd7a2) to build it up.
All core elements of implementing shared element transitions are built correctly as evident from the fact that both fade and slide_top/bottom/right/left work correctly.

First fragment:

```
setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflateTransition(android.R.transition.slide_top));
        Fragment pFragment = PFragment.newInstance(item, transitionName);
        pFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeBounds());

        getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, pFragment)
                    .addSharedElement(sharedImageView, 
    sharedImageView.getTransitionName())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

Second Fragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
if (getArguments() != null) {
    mSId = getArguments().getString(KEY_S);
    transitionName = getArguments().getString(KEY_T);
    img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.s_image);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(img, transitionName);
    Log.e(TAG, "Transition name is " + transitionName);
}
PicassoWithAuth.getImageLoader(getActivity()).with(getActivity())
        .load(R.drawable.dummy).into(img, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        ActivityCompat.startPostponedEnterTransition(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }
});
```

}

ISSUE:
However, i'm not able to make the move transition work, even when i try to apply a manual transition set with changeBounds and changeImageTransformation nothing happens and the new fragment replaces the old one without any transition. Only changing `setSharedElementReturnTransition` to fade or slide_top etc works fine, but nothing that actually reads the bounds and transistions the size.
I'v already tried setting ActivityCompat.postponeEnterTransition(getActivity()); on my new fragment.

QUESTION:
1. Is there a fundamental issue in sharedElementTransition that doesnt allow it to work with nested recyclers? 
2. Is there something i missed in the implementation?

**TIA**

Comment: Have u got any answer for this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I had to skip the whole thing and manually create the move transition on the second fragment when it's created